# Guardar checkbox multiples, inputs text juntos en un formulario en base de datos con ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tengo estos dos pero no sé como combinarlos para guardar tanto como una imagen texto y los checkbox multiples o si tienen algun otro que me puedan proporcionar

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#formulario").submit(formulario1)
    function formulario1(evento){
        evento.preventDefault()
        var datos = new FormData($("#formulario")[0])
        $("#cargando").html("<img src='img/cargar.gif'>")


        $.ajax({
            url: 'agregar.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: datos,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(datos){
                $('#formulario')[0].reset();
                $("#cargando").html(datos)

            }
       })

    }

})
```

y

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#formulario').click(function(){  
           var languages = [];  
           $('.get_value').each(function(){  
                if($(this).is(":checked"))  
                {  
                     languages.push($(this).val());  
                }  
           });  
           languages = languages.toString();  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"agregar.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{languages:languages},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#result').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo personalmente utilizo este código para subir multiples datos desde un mismo formulario y me va muy bien.

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#formulario', function() { 

        //obtenemos datos.
        var data = $(this).serialize();  

        $.ajax({  
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'agregar.php',
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
                  cache: false,
            processData:false,

            success :  function(data) {  
                $('#formulario')[0].reset();
                $("#cargando").html(data);                  
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

> Ejemplo para obtener valor de nuestro multiple checkbox:

**HTML**

```
 <form method="POST" id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     <input type="checkbox" name="buckets[]" value="valor 1">
     <input type="checkbox" name="buckets[]" value="valor 2">
     <input type="checkbox" name="buckets[]" value="valor 3">

     <!-- imagen, otros datos, etc. -->

     <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
</form>

<div id="cargando"><!-- Respuesta AJAX --></div>
```

agregar.php

```
<?php
//var_dump($_POST);

if(!empty($_POST['buckets'])) {
    foreach($_POST['buckets'] as $bucket) {
        echo $bucket; //Mostramos el resultaso seleccionado.                
    }
}

//Continuas con tu código para guardar tus datos.
?>
```

Comment: me sirve tu script pero al momento de mandar los checkbox no los lee y no se si sea el formulario o como debe de acomodarse en el php

Comment: <input type="checkbox" class="get_value"  name="buckets[ ]" id="carrerae" value="Informatica" >Lic./Ing. Informtica</input>

Comment: @ivanrangel prueba con un var_dump($_POST); y asi compruebas que optienes correctamente todos los datos desde el formulario.

Comment: no resibe nada entonces el problema es el php?

Comment: $carrerae= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["buckets[ ] " ]);

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: buckets[] in C:\xampp\htdocs\bde2\agregar.php on line 22
string(0) ""

Comment: @ivanrangel Te he modificado la respuesta, donde podrás ver cómo obtener los resultados de tu múltiple checkbox, la función mysql_real_escape_string() ha sido declarada obsoleta desde PHP 5.5, te aconsejo que utilices sentencias preparadas o PDO para mayor protección.

Comment: Entonces en el php que me muestras trairia mis datos como arreglo y ya solamente tendria que hacer el guardado de los demas datos incluyendo el $_POST['buckets'] o mejor dicho hacer que se guarde el $bucket

Comment: @ivanrangel si, simplemente guarda tus datos en la base datos, espero que te haya ayudado, un saludo

Comment: muchisimas gracias aun me faltan detalles pero ya guarda aunque no se porque guarda un Array al principio debo checar