# Al insertar los datos la tabla queda con datos vacíos, en un formulario básico, hecho con html5

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "bdprueba";


    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $numero=$_POST['numero'];
    $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_contacto (nombre, email, numero, mensaje)
    VALUES ('$nombre', '$email', '$numero', '$mensaje')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "datos ok";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

EL error en el navegador es el siguiente:

```
Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion\conexion.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion\conexion.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: numero in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion\conexion.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: mensaje in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion\conexion.php on line 6
datos ok
```

al revisar los campos en la tabla de la base de datos aparecen vacíos, alguna idea de como resolverlo?

Comment: Te está indicando que seguramente los valores que traes por post no los estás trayendo bien, comprueba el envío.

Comment: Revisa la etiqueta `name` de los elementos del formulario que pasas por POST y cómo lo estás pasando. Al parecer no está recibiendo ninguno de los elementos. Por otra parte, tu consulta escrita así: `INSERT INTO wp_contacto (nombre, email, numero, mensaje)  VALUES ('$nombre', '$email', '$numero', '$mensaje'` es vulnerable, una puerta abierta a la **[Inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)**. Se recomienda usar consultas preparadas. Además, mostrar esto al usuario: `$conn->error;` no es una muy buena idea.

Comment: Deberías añadir el html para revisar las etiquetas, como dice @Carmen, el error parece estar en el metodo con el que recoges la informacion ($_POST)

Comment: Solucionado,faltaban los name, Era todo. ya funciona ok, comenzare a revisar el tema de inyeccion sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar usaría sentencias [mysqli::prepare](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) para obtener un mayor protección hacia su `Base de Datos`.

> Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\conexion\conexion.php on line 3

Simplemente debes reiniciar sus variables al inicio de su programa.

*Ejemplo:*

```
$nombre = $email = $numero = $mensaje = NULL;
```

Para saber si estas obteniendo resultado desde tu formulario podrías hacer un  `var_dump()` con tu variable super global `$_POST`

*Ejemplo:*

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

También revisa que en tu formulario hayas añadido el método `POST` ya que por defecto utiliza `GET` y hayas añadido los atributos `name` a tus `inputs`.

```
<form method="POST">
  <input name="nombre" />
```

*Ejemplo mysqli::prepare:*

```
<?php
    //Reseteo
    $nombre = $email = $numero = $mensaje = NULL;

    //Si esta definida nuestro formulario y no es NULL.
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        //Data Conexión.
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "bdprueba";

        //Data formulario.
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'] ?: '';
        $email = $_POST['email'] ?: '';
        $numero = $_POST['numero'] ?: '';
        $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'] ?: '';

        //Verdadero datos.
        if ($nombre && $email && $numero && $mensaje) {
            //Conexión.
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            //Sentencia preparada.
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_contacto (nombre, email, numero, mensaje) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
            //Ligamos parametros para marcadores ?,?,?,? (nuestras s es decir, declaramos el tipo de dato mysql, en el caso de nuestro nombre es una cadena (string), importante que coincida.
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$nombre,$email,$numero,$mensaje);
            //Ejecutar nuestra sentencia.
            $rc=$stmt->execute();

            //Comprobamos si se ejecuto correctamente.
            if (false===$rc) {
                exit('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
            } else {
                echo "$nombre sus datos se insertaron correctamente";
            }
            $stmt->close();//Cerramos sentencia
        }
    }          

    ?>
```

> **Nota:** Especificación del tipo de caracteres (bind_param)
>     **i**     la variable correspondiente es de tipo entero
>     **d**     la variable correspondiente es de tipo double
>     **s**     la variable correspondiente es de tipo string
>     **b**     la variable correspondiente es un blob y se envía en paquetes

Comment: Estaba ya buscando informacion sobre  inyeccionSQL y me encuentro su respuesta quedo agradecido, ya funciona correctamente!, Me quedo claro el concepto,ahora estoy buscando informacion para que se recargue el formulario en la misma pagina, si tiene alguna informacion sera de gran ayuda!

Comment: @Developer me alegro que te haya servido el ejemplo, para que no se recargue la página, debes implementar `AJAX`, te dejo un posible respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53277/guardar-checkbox-multiples-inputs-text-juntos-en-un-formulario-en-base-de-datos/53291#53291